# Is a used 1998 LeMond Buenos Aires worth $450?

Tags: road-bike, used-bike

This is the bike I'm interested in buying: http://www.bikepedia.com/quickbike/BikeSpecs.aspx?year=1998&brand=LeMond&model=Buenos+Aires.  The bike is in good condition upon inspection and a test drive.  Is it worth $450?

What things do I need to look out for when buying such a bike?  If I were to get it, what should I look out for when using it?

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Vrume. We cannot tell you what it's worth *to you*. They cost $1300-$1500 when new. See this [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=1998+LeMond+Buenos+Aires+&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). I'll be voting to close this question though, because shopping questions go out of date too quickly. We look forward to other questions from you, or even a few answers :-)

Comment: I feel there ia a broader question here, can a quality bike from yesteryear still be useful today. Others might have more to add on this.

Answer (score 1):

It's a well speced bike, Reynolds tubing is top quality. Given the 1998 price tag of $1300, I would say the current price is good. It will be harder to ride than a modern bike, but not by too much.

Watch out for rust around the bottom bracket covers and cable stops. Early model carbon forks can wear also. It's 8 speed, so still easy to buy chains and cassettes for.

Comment: Why would it be harder to ride?

Comment: It is heavier, has less gears with a limited range. The 12 to 26 tooth cassette is more suited to racing, but you could change this. (this answer is a factual as I could make it for an opinion based question and still someone sees the need to vote it down).

Comment: @KimRyan we don't see much downvoting here, but at a guess perhaps someone disagreed with *It will be harder to ride than a modern bike* ...

Comment: That price might be fine depending on the area. I was recently helping a coworker look for bikes. $450 would have been similar to the asking price for similar stuff in my area. Anything with real components (RSX, 105, Ultegra) as opposed to generic Shimano or even worse components was at least $400 asking price.

Comment: Unusual to see a triple chain ring on a road bike.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say probably [not](http://www.bicyclebluebook.com/SearchListingDetail.aspxhttp://www.bicyclebluebook.com/SearchListingDetail.aspx?id=79090&make=697&model=47597) unless it's been significantly upgraded.  I am always wary buying used carbon, but used carbon that is far more than a decade old would worry me.  If the fork (in particular) goes, you'll likely be paying more than the worth of the bike to replace it, even with a cheaper non carbon fork.

Comment: You can get an alloy fork for around $100.

Answer (score 0):

I have a LeMond Zurich of similar vintage (2000). Bike is a dream to ride. To me, that's a fair price ... and you get to ride a bike with a true champion's name on it.